# how to store salt and password hash with the same file that has been encrypted

Tags: python, encryption

i am building a software with python and qt designer that take picture and encrypt it
when reach into saving the password hash and salt (i've chosen to write them with encrypted file it self )I've faced a problem which is i am not getting the same output of hash
i dont know what i'm doing wrong

this is the encrypting function

```
        global pic_path,getOpenFileName
        password_provided =  self.pass_entry1.text() # This is input in the form of a string
        password = password_provided.encode()  # Convert to type bytes
        salt =bytes(os.urandom(16))  # recommend using a key from os.urandom(16), must be of type bytes
        pass_hash= hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
               'sha256', # The hash digest algorithm for HMAC
               password_provided.encode('utf-8'), # Convert the password to bytes
               salt, # Provide the salt
               100000 # It is recommended to use at least 100,000 iterations of SHA-256 
               )
        print("salt: "+str(salt))
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
               algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
               length=32,
               salt=salt,
               iterations=100000,
               backend=default_backend()
               )
        key = base64.urlsafe_b64encode(kdf.derive(password))  # Can only use kdf once
        file = open(pic_path,'rb+')
        fdata=file.read()
        f = Fernet(key)
        encrypted = f.encrypt(fdata)  # Encrypt the bytes. The returning object is of type bytes
        file.close()
        try:
                os.mkdir(os.getcwd()+"/encrypted")
        except:
                pass
        pic_path=os.getcwd()+"/encrypted/"+name
        fileencrypted=open(os.path.splitext(pic_path)[0]+'.cod','wb+')
        fileencrypted.write(salt)
        fileencrypted.write(pass_hash)
        fileencrypted.write(encrypted)
        fileencrypted.close()
        self.error_label.setText("file encrypted scessfully")
```

and this is the decrypting function which am still working on

```
    def decrypte(self):
        file= open(filename,'rb')
        salt= file.read(16)
        password_hash= file.read(80)[16:80]
        given_pass= self.pass_entry_dec.text()
        key_given=hashlib.pbkdf2_hmac(
               'sha256', # The hash digest algorithm for HMAC
               given_pass.encode('utf-8'), # Convert the password to bytes
               salt, # Provide the salt
               100000 # It is recommended to use at least 100,000 iterations of SHA-256 
               )
        print("salt: "+str(salt))
        kdf = PBKDF2HMAC(
               algorithm=hashes.SHA256(),
               length=32,
               salt=salt,
               iterations=100000,
               backend=default_backend()
               )

        print("this is the given password hash:"+ str(key_given)
            +"\n this is the password hash from file"+str(password_hash))
```

this is the output I'm getting the salt is the same but the password hash isn't

```
salt: b'\xabS\x04\xbe7!\x192i\x1d\xc6\x85\xf4\xd3\x87\x0e'
salt: b'\xabS\x04\xbe7!\x192i\x1d\xc6\x85\xf4\xd3\x87\x0e'
this is the given password hash: +b'r\xda\xa8\xbd~\xac\xc3Cd\xef\x14\xa3L\x9f\x17\x8f%Z*n\xc4!aLc?\xebCB\xf3H\\'
this is the password hash from file b'\x8f%Z*n\xc4!aLc?\xebCB\xf3H\\gAAAAABfd20OSsKipnqDuh6USgKr3Z8KiEvIoieTDTRLYZE'
```

Comment: You seem to be reading the wrong portion of the file. After `file.read(16)` the position doesn't reset, it stays there. So `file.read(64)` should read the password, if it is 64 bytes long.

Comment: oh thanks thats exactly what i was looking for